# Generate LULC maps using Sentinel data of European Space Agency?

Tags: classification, landsat, sentinel-2, sentinel-snap, image-classification

I found out that Sentinel data is of 10m x 10m resolution whereas LANDSAT data is of 30m x 30m resolution. Did anyone come across research in which Sentinel data is used for making LULC maps or is applied for some other purposes?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, there are many projects on going using Sentinel-2 as input for land cover maps production

A few examples:

[Inglada, J.; Vincent, A.; Arias, M.; Tardy, B.; Morin, D.; Rodes, I. Operational High Resolution Land Cover Map Production at the Country Scale Using Satellite Image Time Series. Remote Sens. 2017, 9, 95.](https://www.mdpi.com/2072-4292/9/1/95)

Patrick Griffiths, Claas Nendel, Patrick Hostert, Intra-annual reflectance composites from Sentinel-2 and Landsat for national-scale crop and land cover mapping,Remote Sensing of Environment, Volume 220, 2019,Pages 135-151,
ISSN 0034-4257,
https://doi.org/10.1016/j.rse.2018.10.031.